# Status bar is changing color to the 'windowBackground' instead of using 'colorPrimaryDark'

Tags: android, xamarin, android-appcompat

I'm styling my android mobile app using AppCompat.
It's running android 6.0 which is API 23.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="FeedingTime.FeedingTime" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" android:installLocation="auto">
    <uses-sdk />
    <application android:icon="@drawable/Icon" android:label="Feeding Time" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Here is my style.xml:

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>

    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/background_color</item>

    <item name="colorPrimary">#6497b1</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#005b96</item>
  </style>
```

Here is the XML of the Activity layout where the problem exist:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
  <include
        android:id="@+id/toolbarHistoryActivity"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />
  <ListView
      android:minWidth="25px"
      android:minHeight="25px"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="4"
      android:id="@+id/listViewHistory" />
  <Button
      android:text="Clear History"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:id="@+id/btnClearHistory" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm running into a problem, in home screen activity the status bar color is set to dark blue as expected, but when i open the second activity my status bar changes color, it's no longer using the 'colorPrimaryDark' but rather a darker version of the color i have in 'windowBackground'.

Why is that?

Comment: post your manifest file as well!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `Coordinatorlayout` as root and use `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"`

instead of `Linearlayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
```

you can also programetically set `StatusBar` color in your `Activity`:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
getWindow().setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.your_color));  //change color here
}
```

Comment: I've changed the root to 'android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout' and now it works, thank you sir for the suggestion.